# Django view render_to_response to bootstrap/foundation modal

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I was wondering how do I render_to_response to some modal inside a html file? Basically, I want the view to force a modal to pop up once it is done doing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using ajax, call the view using ajax and return data in form of a json. Use javascript to pop out the modal and show content accordingly.